# Pixel size of images

Tags: android, image, screen, pixel

i want a default pixel size of image in this size should be adaptable for all type of screen size.Anyone can help me please, How to fix image in all type of mobile screen. it cant be stretched out.
 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, You cannot have a Default size...

If you are developing a Mobile app, then you should detect the User's screen size and use an appropriate dimension of the picture there....

Have at least three different variations of the same picture for different screen sizes..

Android Has an inbuilt way of doing this Have a look at this : [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: thanks, but i have one doubt, i put my all images in mdpi, if i run this app to large screen the images are stretched.... what i want to do please help me...

Comment: @NandhiniKumar Yes the Larger screen device will need bigger resolution Images to display without stretching...

Try getting a Bigger ( Higher resolution/ Higher Pixel Ratio ) image and Put it under the HDPI and XHDPI folders ... that should solve the problem.

Comment: okay,got your point, but if i put the same images with high ratio and resolution, its having a possible to increase my App size right? am so confused sir...?

Comment: can you send me a pixel resolution and ratio for mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi

Comment: @NandhiniKumar and yes Including High Density Images will definetely increase your app size... But we can't help it.

Comment: yes you'r correct...what about this size.. xlarge screens are 960dp x 720dp
large screens are 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are 470dp x 320dp
small screens are 426dp x 320dp

Comment: Google Suggests these Standard Ratios :   [Refer to Ducumentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources)  
36x36 for low-density  
48x48 for medium-density  
72x72 for high-density 
96x96 for extra high-density

Comment: i referred that document... May i use this size?'

Comment: thank you so much sir...thanks for your helping your all points are valuable to me thanks

Comment: if i including high density images it will surely increase my app size, how to solve this issue? its having any possible to reduce my app size?

Comment: All the ways of reducing the APK file Size are mentioned here :
[Click here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/)

Comment: If you are asking me only for the Pictures... then I would suggest you to use high compression and lossless Formats (PNG and JPEG) only .. they take less space without compromising on quality..

Comment: oh nice, if i use .png and .jpeg format pictures in mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi folders means its take only less space right?

Comment: Yes.... The article mentions ways of reducing the PNG and JPEG file size using some Optimizer applications .... try those it may help..

Answer (score 1):

There is no default pixel size.

You will either have to design images for each bucket you wish to support, or try and create a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for your images.

The [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) document has everything you need to having your UI scale nicely across devices.

Comment: thanks, but i have one doubt, i put my all images in mdpi, if i run this app to large screen the images are stretched.... what i want to do please help me?

Comment: @NandhiniKumar That's because larger devices would be hdpi or even xhdpi and so on. You'll need to design larger graphics for those.

Comment: okay,got your point, but if i put the same images with high ratio and resolution, its having a possible to increase my App size right? am so confused sir...?

Comment: can you send me a pixel resolution and ratio for mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi